# I cannot remove observers that I register

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnotificationcenter

I am registering some observers in my application to show a controller when timeout occurs:

```
for(Ad* ad in ads){
    if(ad.published){
        [ad resetTimer];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:ad name:@"TouchBegan" object:nil];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:ad selector:@selector(resetTimer) name:@"TouchBegan" object:nil];
    }
}
```

In Ad class, I try to remove observers in dealloc:

```
-(void) dealloc {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"TouchBegan" object:nil];
}
```

But it seems that there still exists an observer after dealloc.

Ads array is a property of a Shop class:

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSArray<Ad>* ads;
```

How I can completely remove observers that I register?

Comment: How do you know there still exists an observer after `dealloc`?

Comment: Because selector triggers

Comment: Is `dealloc` even called?

Comment: If the selector triggers then the `Ad` instance wasn't deallocated.

Comment: What you're doing, by the way, is very dangerous and unusual. It is legal for one object to register another object with the notification center, but it is not advisable, and it is certainly not advisable for one object to do the registering and another object to do the removing, as you can easily get confused / unbalanced — and since the notification center can't be introspected, this sort of unbalance is extraordinarily difficult to track down. I would suggest simplifying your code and putting it all into the Ad class.

Answer (score 1):

It is safe to remove `self` as observer for all names in dealloc `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];`

Comment: @Burak No, this line removes `self` as an observer for all names.

Comment: @rmaddy thanks, updated reply - didn't realised it might be unclear

Comment: I did that but selector still triggers. I am getting crazy

Comment: Be sure `dealloc` get's called as you expect it. With ARC (and especially block syntax - but I don't see that here) it's not a good place to unregister.

Answer (score 0):

If the observer is added to a view controller, I strongly recommend adding it in `viewWillAppear` and removing it in `viewWillDisappear`.

`[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:someObserver];` will remove even the super class observers which is highly unrecommended (except in `dealloc` because the object is unloaded) but in `viewWillDisappear` you should remove the observers one by one by using `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"TouchBegan" object:nil];`

Comment: Observer is added to objects in ads array. When I refresh the application, I set this array to nil and dealloc works. But observers are not removed.